# Password Reset-Sending mail doesnt work

Tags: python, django, email, django-mailer

```
Setting.py-

EMAIL_BACKEND = "mailer.backend.DbBackend"
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = "[.....]"

EMAIL_HOST          = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'tester@@abcd'
EMAIL_HOST_USER     = 'tester.abcd@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT          = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS       = True

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  = 'tester.abcd@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_ADMIN_EMAIL  = 'tester.abcd@gmail.com'
TEMPORARY_CC_EMAIL = 'tester.abcd@gmail.com'
CONTACTUS_EMAIL = 'tester.abcd@gmail.com'
JOBAPPLY_EMAIL = 'tester.abcd@gmail.com'

urls.py:

urlpatterns = patterns('django.contrib.auth.views',
 url(r'^password-reset/$', 'password_reset', {
      'template_name': 'profiles/password_reset_form.html',
    'password_reset_form': PassResetForm
  }, name='password-reset'),
 url(r'^password-reset-process/$', 'password_reset_done', {
    'template_name': 'profiles/password_reset_done.html',
  }, name='password-reset-done'),
 url(r'^password-reset-confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,13})-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    'password_reset_confirm',
    {'template_name': 'profiles/password_reset_confirm.html',},
    name='password-reset-confirm'),
 url(r'^password-reset-complete', 'password_reset_complete', {
    'template_name': 'profiles/password_reset_complete.html',
  }, name='password-reset-complete'),
```

This is my code wheni enter my mail and click submit it correctly redirects to the next page but mail is not send,is there anything pblm with this code

Comment: instead of showing your url patterns you should better show your view which is meant to send the mail...

Comment: am using django-password reset

Answer (score 0):

You should start by testing if the problem comes from your code or the email backend.

Here is how to setup the Django console email backend:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

This should output emails in the console when you are running the server on your local dev machine `python manage.py runserver`.

If the emails are printed correctly into the console, then there is something wrong with your configuration either here:

```
EMAIL_HOST          = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'tester@@abcd'
EMAIL_HOST_USER     = 'tester.abcd@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT          = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS       = True
```

or here:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "mailer.backend.DbBackend"
```

Comment: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend',i tried this its working fine,mail displayed in my terminal

Comment: That would mean that the backend is not sending the mail or it's going to spam maybe. Did you check spam folder?

Comment: What if you use this backend: `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`?

Comment: Very insightful... So?